# PrimeFaces TabView dynamic Duplicate Component

Tags: primefaces

I'm having trouble using dynamic = "false" in the p: tabview of Primefaces. If it is true how dynamic = "true" everything works normal, but if it is false, it is my need, by clicking the button it sends the screen, it does not validate and doubles the button block as in the image below.

Here is the behavior:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za988.png

Comment: By doing tests I realized that if I put the buttons above TabView it works normal and does not duplicate, but I can not do this because it breaks the layout of the project.

Comment: Did you checked if your commandButton has a update tag with id of tabview?. I've faced the same problem with panelGrid, after save panelGrid it was duplicated.